# Pynput same Controller keyboard and mouse

Tags: python, overwrite, pynput

I know the Problem but dont how to fix it. Controller gets overwritten but how can I change that?

```
import pynput

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller


keyboard = Controller()
mouse = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.cmd_l),  keyboard.press('d')
keyboard.release(Key.cmd_l), keyboard.release('d')

mouse.move = (58, 535)
mouse.click(Button.left, 1)

with keyboard.pressed(Key.cmd_l):
    keyboard.press(Key.cmd_l)
    keyboard.release(Key.cmd_l)
    keyboard.press('d')
    keyboard.release('d')
```

Answer (score 12):

Import with an alias.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyboardController
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController

keyboard = KeyboardController()
mouse = MouseController()
```